# DownloadManager with cookie authentication

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager

I'm trying to get a zip file using DownloadManager parsing a cookie with a JSESSIONID from my server. I'm getting this JSESSIONID doing all my process login using HTTPCLIENT lib and setting a variable JSESSIONID for later use in my DownloadManager request.

My download request:

```
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(htmlUrlDownload));

    request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + JSESSIONID);
    request.addRequestHeader(Constants.USER_AGENT, Constants.TARGET_REQUEST_HEADER);

    request.setDescription("Baixando " + metaDado.getType());
    request.setTitle("Download");
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

    String nameFile = offlineUuid + ".zip";

    fileName = nameFile;

    filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
            + File.separator + fileName;

    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameFile);

    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);
```

The problem is that download never starts and the COLUMN_REASON returns a code to [ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)

But if I try to download the same file using a dropbox link without authentication or using httpclient,  it's works perfectly, what am I doing wrong?

How can I get a better msg error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing wrong in your code, seems like your server is responding with HTTP redirect staus code, which is causing DownloadManager to fail to process download.

**From Android Docs** :-

> public static final int ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE
>
> Added in API level 9 Value of COLUMN_REASON when an HTTP code was
>   received that download manager can't handle.

See below code snippet:-

**From Android Framework source code [DownloadManger.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/DownloadManager.java)**

```
case Downloads.Impl.STATUS_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE:
                case Downloads.Impl.STATUS_UNHANDLED_REDIRECT:
                    return ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE;
```

So you need to check your Server logs for this issue, or pass direct file url to download manager which doesn't cause any redirect.

Also please note that you need below two permissions in your Androidmanifest.xml for download to work as expected

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: I have no access to it. When I said my server, was the server I was using, did understand? :(

Comment: anyway redirects are not supported in download manager, and because of redirects your download request is failing. **[This link might be useful to you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13212978/1677824)**..

Comment: have you earned the bount?? You're right, my problem is exactly about redirecting.

Comment: nope.. every bounty has some time limit(along with grace period), if you don't assign it to someone, it lost for forever.